# Extract-Archive to traditional folder structure

Tags: powershell, unzip

When trying to unzip files traditionally in Windows, it unzips to the name of the zip file as a folder with the files embedded into the folder itself.  I am unable to recreate this using the Extract-Archive Cmdlet.  Here is the code section for this that I have:
`Get-ChildItem 'path of zip' -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'path to extract' -Force`
While running this, the unzip process works fine.  I am just wondering if there is a way to keep the traditional unzip file/folder structure when using the Expand-Archive Cmdlet

Thank you

Comment: this question is better suited for asking in superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the destination folder in parameter `DestinationPath`. If the folder with the name of the zipfile does not yet exist, it will be created:

```
$sourcePath  = 'path of zip file(s)'
$destination = 'path to extract'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.zip' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.BaseName
    $_ | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $target -Force
}
```